# HTTP POST and WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Well, I know this may be stupid question. But I have searched the net and some how could not the answer to this simple question. Getting to the point : How to handle http post request in wso2 esb. Can someone please give me an example illustrating the implementation of a proxy service that handles http post requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to configure anything specially for POST request. The only thing you have to consider is the content type of the request and response. And based on that content type you have to use appropriate message builder and formatter in axis2.xml.

If you observe any issues with this, provide HTTP POST request that is sent to ESB and the accepted response from the service (With all HTTP Content Types etc)

Comment: ok..well actually my final motive is to develop a service(within esb) that sends/receives emails and i wanted to pass the required parameters like subject, body, to(a list of email addresses),etc through http post....any thoughts on how to do this? by the way i have a proxy service which whenever called sends  a FIXED email to a FIXED email address from a FIXED email id..and i want to make it as generic as possible..